# the unit of the distance and duration of road in osmbonuspack

Tags: android, openstreetmap

I am using the **OSMbonuspack library**   to display road in osm map , i succeeded  to get the   distance  and the  duration  but i don't know what's the unit .Here 's the code :

`Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "distance="+road.mLength,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "durée="+road.mDuration,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();`

A snapshot of the  result is :[image][image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you find that in API documentation

- **length of the route is in km.**
- **duration of the trip is in sec.**

take a look at the [source code](https://code.google.com/p/osmbonuspack/source/browse/trunk/OSMBonusPack/src/org/osmdroid/bonuspack/Road.java?r=25)